# How to set Class-Path header with dependencies?

Tags: sbt

I'm using latest version of sbt 0.13.7, and I'd like to set `Class-Path` header of my `MANIFEST.MF` file with all the project dependencies, and I don't really know how. I did read [Configure packaging](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Package.html).

I do know how to set other headers like `Main-Class`:

```
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("mypackage.MyClass")
```

I know it can be done with the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin, but I don't want to create one big jar, just a small jar, that includes all the dependencies.

I found I could set `Class-Path` with `*.jar`, as shown in this snippet:

```
packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) +=
  Package.ManifestAttributes(java.util.jar.Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH -> "*.jar")
```

It appears a kind of workaround not a final solution. Any guidance very welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with sbt-assembly plugin for a single project? After all, that's what the plugin does and what you seem to be up to - bundle all deps in a single jar.

Comment: I like to see clearly all 3rd party `jar`s I'm embedding and their sizes.  I think the `*.jar` trick solves my problem, if I copy all the dependencies to the same folder.